# Using ArcSDEQuerier of FME

Tags: fme-form

I am trying the ArcSDEQuerier transformer of FMEBbut it doesn't work when I specify the attribute :

```
name ='TEST'
```

for the search (Where).

How does this transformer work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using FME2011 then you will probably want to switch to the FeatureReader transformer. It's designed to be a replacement for the ArcSDEQuerier (and OracleQuerier).

Otherwise, if TEST an attribute you are trying to match to a database field (name), you would need the syntax:

```
name = @Value(TEST)
```

If TEST is a text attribute, then it's preferable to put quotes around it, as in:

```
name = '@Value(TEST)'
```

And everything is MOST DEFINITELY case sensitive, so "TEST" is not the same as "test" or "Test" or "TesT" and it's value will be case sensitive too (so name will not match TEST if the two respective values were - for example - "ABC" and "abc")